# Python, why is capsys not defined?

Tags: python, pytest

I feel like I'm missing something completely obvious, but everywhere I see capsys mentioned it's described as built-in and all example code I see doesn't import anything to use it. Searching around I have a hard time even finding documentation on it, just people talking about it in threads.

Despite this, if I try to use capsys I get a "NameError: name 'capsys' is not defined" error. What am I missing? If it built-in shouldn't it just...work?

Python 3.9.4

Edit 1: Including the test code in question

```
def test_print():
  print("test string")
  captured = capsys.readouterr()
  assert captured.out == "test string\n"
```

Comment: Is there **any** library you use in `python` without importing it?

Comment: I've never _heard_ of `capsys`, in my 20 years of writing Python. When you talk about "everywhere I see capsys mentioned", a link might be useful. (A quick Google implies it's part of `pytest`, which is not Python itself, and thus needs to be installed/imported/etc).

Comment: I think it's a pytest fixture and it seems to be used by having it as a parameter of your test method. E.g. https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function

Answer (score 0):

`capsys` is a builtin fixture in `pytest`.  In `pytest` you indicate that a fixture should be used in a particular test by including it's name as a parameter of the test.  You should have

```
def test_print(capsys):
  print("test string")
  captured = capsys.readouterr()
  assert captured.out == "test string\n"
```

Now when you `> pytest your_module.py`, the `capsys` fixture will be accessible.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html

Comment: Thank you, I was not familiar with what fixtures were and both 1) missed that they were being passed to the function in examples I found, and 2) still wouldn't have recognized why that would work.

Comment: Yeah, the `pytest` system for passing fixtures to tests is pretty opaque and magic since it relies on the _name_ of the argument in the test function.